# Ввести текст из файла

Tags: c#, массивы, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно загнать текст в массив. Очень-очень нужно...
задание такое: Ввести текст из файла, а также массив символов-разделителей с клавиатуры.

Comment: сессия грядет.

Comment: 1) что значит "загнать текст в массив"? 

2) вы пишете "Ввести текст из файла". Так все же **ввести** или **вывести**? **из файла** или **в файл**? 

Ваше задание звучит несколько странно

Comment: ну строки, слова и разделители записать ввиде массива
ввести текст из файла

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a.aspx) про метод String.Split() - если производительность не так важна, он должен вам подойти.